# XPath in PowerShell

Tags: .net, ruby, powershell, xpath

I am converting some `ruby` scripts to `posh`:

```
> gem install nokogiri

> irb

> require 'nokogiri'

> $html = Nokogiri::HTML("<div><img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/first.png' />
                       <img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/second.png' /></div>")

> $html.xpath('//img[contains(@src,"first")]')

# Output: <img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/first.png' />
```

In PowerShell, I have:

```
> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.Linq")

> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.XPath")

> $html = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse("<div>
                       <img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/first.png' />
                       <img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/second.png' /></div>")

> [System.Xml.XPath.Extensions]::XPathSelectElement($html, 
                                  '//img[contains(@src,"first")]')

# It displays the properties of XElement type object
```

How to get the same output?

Is there a better way parsing html in PowerShell v.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.ToString()` and you will get the same output.

Here is a simpler alternative which produces the same:

```
$html = [xml] "<div><img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/first.png' />
                    <img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/second.png' /></div>"
$html.SelectSingleNode('//img[contains(@src,"first")]').OuterXml
```

or even

```
($html.div.img | ?{ $_.src -match 'first' }).outerxml
```

Note that I am assuming you are dealing with `XML` as per your own PowerShell example (I am not used to handling `HTML`)…

Answer (score 2):

Another way for query XML just using CMDLET:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<div>
<img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/first.png' />
<img src='//127.0.0.1:5598/user/second.png' />
</div>
"@

(select-xml -xml $xml -xpath '//img[contains(@src,"first")]' ) | % { $_.node.src }
```

Answer (score 1):

another alternative using invoke-webrequest (PS V3) :

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("c:\temp\test.html")
$html=$ie.Document
$html.images|% { if ($_.src -match "first") {echo $_.outerHTML}}
```

note that if its not a local file you can use :

```
 $html = Invoke-WebRequest "http://yourURL"
```

then parse `$html.ParsedHtml.body`

Comment: Good thinking, nice approach! Don't forget to close IE, though :]